# How to load records in mysql to one form from another form by separate by commas C#

Tags: c#, mysql, forms, textbox

I want to get mysql from one form by clicking a button and then it goes to another form and show the data on a textbox separating by commas.

Here is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog='yadb';username=root;password=");
    //command = connection.CreateCommand();
    string query = "SELECT `tpno` FROM `member` WHERE `electorate_cluster`='"+comboBox1.Text+"'";
    command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        //MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `tpno` FROM `member` ", connection);
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //string s = "tpno";
            sms sm = new sms();
            sm.mobno.Text = reader.GetString("tpno".Split(","));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In here I used mysql database to store data and mobno.text means the 2nd form textbox

Btw I am new to C#

Comment: Is the problem that you can't access label from another Form?

Comment: no this code is not working.this code doesn't load tp.numbers from database and not splitting it on comma and splitting error is cannot covert string to char

Answer (score 0):

you can have parameterized constructor for your second form...and pass data what you need from frist form and make sure your paramterized constructor is calling default constructor.

Something like this

```
public class sm : Form
{
public sm()
{
   IntializeComponent();
}
public sm(string data):this()
{
     //Assign the data wherever you want
}

}
```

In first form button click event do this

```
 while (reader.Read())
            {
                //string s = "tpno";
                sms sm = new sms(reader.GetString("tpno".Split(",")));
                 sm.Show();
            }
```